# Как получить значение словаря зная только другой значение этого словаря?

Tags: python, json

Есть json:

```
{
"users": [
{"Id": 1,
"Cash: 123"},
{"Id": 2,
"Cash: 456"},
{"Id": 3,
"Cash: 789"}]
}
```

Мне нужно узнать Cash пользователя зная это айди
Должно быть так:

```
print(get_cash(1))
Output: 123
```

Comment: [Ю кен юс гугл серч энд файнд зис информэшн](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418270/how-to-get-value-from-dictionary-using-key-from-another-dictionary-as-the-name)

Comment: Переведи на русский.

Answer (score -2):

```
def get_cash(num,dict):
   for it in dict['users']:
       if it['Id']==num:
           return it['Cash']
```

But it return first entry i mean

```
{
"users": [
{"Id": 1,
"Cash: 123"},
{"Id": 2,
"Cash: 456"},
{"Id": 2,
"Cash: THIS NEVER WILL BE RETURNED BCRSE ID IS 2 ALSO AS PREVIOSLY"}]
}
```

Comment: Переведи на русский. И второй блок кода какой-то непонятный, к тому же, с ошибкой.

Comment: Вопрос был задан на английском,- международном языке программирования: вся документация написана на английском. Не вижу смысла переводить элементарные фразы на русский, непонятно для кого. С ошибкой мб потому что это не код, а формат json с вольной интерпритацией?

Comment: @ganz Я раньше тоже на том же языке отвечал, на котором вопросы задают, но тут есть определённые правила, это русскоязычный раздел SO, тут всё должно быть на русском.

Comment: @ganz, находясь на русскоязычном сайте надо писать на русском. И вопросы тут задавать на английском тоже нельзя. Если хочешь писать на английском, то отвечай на англоязычном. Именно в json'е и ошибка: `"Cash: 123"` должно быть `"Cash": 123`, ещё так же 456, а `"Cash: THIS` - вообще `"Cash": "THIS`. К тому же, это копипаст из вопроса и как он соотносится с фразой _"я имею в виду" ("i mean"),_ я вообще не понимаю.

Comment: А, я всё-таки понял, что ты имел в виду.

Comment: @Qwertiy учи инглиш, особенно его разговорный вариант, где я много чего опускаю, ну то есть с тебя хреновый модер,- ответ дан на вопрос полностью на языке понятном задавшему, но нет же б модеры тыркают своими хотелками, идите нахер,- больше одного незаслуженого дизлайка не поймаю.

Comment: @ganz, иди и читай правила сайта. А минус вообще не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy сам читай, я и так знаю что я могу выражать своё мнение и требовать уважения к нему см права человека, а если ваши правила нарушают права человека  то идите нахер, ну и как на счёт того чтобы выполнить обязаности модера и почистить ответы от твоего флуда?